# Query - Match Name to Multiple Unique Types

Tags: ms-access, distinct

I'm trying to create an Access 2013 database query to display all insurance policy holders that have more than one type of insurance. I am not interested in policy holders that have only one type of insurance. If a policy holder has more than one type of insurance I need a list showing the policy holder “NAME” and each unique insurance “TYPE”.

The database table is named “INSURANCE” and contains a large number of record fields but I need to isolate only two record fields. Here is a sample of 15 records:

[image]

So, in the above example, I am not interested in “Jones” or “Miller” since they have only a single type of insurance. Since “Smith’, “Brown”, "Davis" and "Wilson" have multiple types of insurance I need a list showing their names and each unique type of insurance. For the above example, the query would produce the following result:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- this should work for a starter
select distinct MyTable.Name, MyTable.Type
from MyTable
where Name in (
        select t1.Name
        from (
            select t0.Name, t0.Type
            from (
                select distinct MyTable.Name, MyTable.Type
                from MyTable
                ) as t0
            group by t0.Name, t0.Type
            ) as t1
        group by t1.Name
        having count(*) > 1
        );
```

Comment: Great answer byrdzeye!! It worked perfectly with the large data file I had!! I had actually found a solution but it took me 3 separate queries to accomplish what you did with only one query. Thank you!